# Dictionary with Semicolon data to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have data **scraped** from web that I want to put in a pandas dataframe

the **scraped** json data is in this format:

```
[{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":0,"dt_notific;dt_inicio_sintomas;bairro_resid__estadia;ap_residencia_estadia;evolu\ufffd\ufffdo;dt_\ufffdbito;CEP;Data_atualiza\ufffd\ufffdo":"06/05/2020;06/05/2020;CACHAMBI;3.2;\ufffdbito;07/05/2020;20771330;11/07/2020"}},{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":1,"dt_notific;dt_inicio_sintomas;bairro_resid__estadia;ap_residencia_estadia;evolu\ufffd\ufffdo;dt_\ufffdbito;CEP;Data_atualiza\ufffd\ufffdo":"06/05/2020;05/05/2020;TIJUCA;2.2;\ufffdbito;12/05/2020;20261120;11/07/2020"}},{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":2,"dt_notific;dt_inicio_sintomas;bairro_resid__estadia;ap_residencia_estadia;evolu\ufffd\ufffdo;dt_\ufffdbito;CEP;Data_atualiza\ufffd\ufffdo":"25/04/2020;25/04/2020;JACAREPAGUA;4.0;\ufffdbito;25/04/2020;22753211;11/07/2020"}} 
(...)
```

And I would like to achieve a pandas dataframe with info similar to this:

```
 0   dt_notific             50613 non-null  object 
 1   dt_inicio_sintomas     50603 non-null  object 
 2   bairro_resid__estadia  50640 non-null  object 
 3   ap_residencia_estadia  50640 non-null  float64
 4   evolucao               50640 non-null  object 
 5   dt_obito               4727 non-null   object 
 6   CEP                    50640 non-null  int64  
 7   dt_registro            50640 non-null  object
```

Til now, I can only achieve that by saving the data in a file and performing crazy stuff using a text editor.

What can i programatically do to achieve the same result?
The only interesting data to me is the one associated with big key divided by semicolon ; (the value itself is also semicolon divided)

Comment: I don't see the value `50613` in your json

Comment: Scrapped means thrown away.  You mean __scraped__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gustav Rasmussen who gave me a way of coping with this problem.

His answer had some important insights I wasn't aware (as the one to use module 2 "%2" to get only the field I needed and discard the OBJECTID field)

I've made some adjustments to his code and now everything works as I was expecting. Final code was

```
    j2Str = json.dumps(j2)
    val = j2Str.replace(r"u\ufffd", "?").replace(r"\ufffd", "?")
    j = json.loads(val)

    i = 0
    listoflists = []
    a_list = []
    for line in j:
        for v in line.values():
            for key, value in v.items():
                # print(key, value)
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    a_list = value.split(';')
                    listoflists.append(a_list[:])
                i += 1

    df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array(listoflists),
                       columns=["dt_notific","dt_inicio_sintomas","bairro_resid__estadia","ap_residencia_estadia","evolcao","dt_obito","CEP","Data_atualizacao"])

    print(df.info())
```

And the resulting dataframe info:

```
 0   dt_notific             2000 non-null   object
 1   dt_inicio_sintomas     2000 non-null   object
 2   bairro_resid__estadia  2000 non-null   object
 3   ap_residencia_estadia  2000 non-null   object
 4   evolcao                2000 non-null   object
 5   dt_obito               2000 non-null   object
 6   CEP                    2000 non-null   object
 7   Data_atualizacao       2000 non-null   object
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the list as a multiline string, replace `u\ufffd` by `?`, load as `JSON`,
loop over keys and values, conditionally saving to lists, and finally use these lists to create a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

val = r"""
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 0,
            "dt_notific;dt_inicio_sintomas;bairro_resid__estadia;ap_residencia_estadia;evolu\ufffd\ufffdo;dt_\ufffdbito;CEP;Data_atualiza\ufffd\ufffdo":
            "06/05/2020;06/05/2020;CACHAMBI;3.2;\ufffdbito;07/05/2020;20771330;11/07/2020"
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 1,
            "dt_notific;dt_inicio_sintomas;bairro_resid__estadia;ap_residencia_estadia;evolu\ufffd\ufffdo;dt_\ufffdbito;CEP;Data_atualiza\ufffd\ufffdo":
            "06/05/2020;05/05/2020;TIJUCA;2.2;\ufffdbito;12/05/2020;20261120;11/07/2020"
        }
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 2,
            "dt_notific;dt_inicio_sintomas;bairro_resid__estadia;ap_residencia_estadia;evolu\ufffd\ufffdo;dt_\ufffdbito;CEP;Data_atualiza\ufffd\ufffdo":
            "25/04/2020;25/04/2020;JACAREPAGUA;4.0;\ufffdbito;25/04/2020;22753211;11/07/2020"
        }
    }
]
""".replace(r"u\ufffd", "?").replace(r"\ufffd", "?")

j = json.loads(val)

i = 0
k = 0
index = []
col = []
for line in j:
    for v in line.values():
        for key, value in v.items():
            # print(key, value)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                index.append(value)
            else:
                col.append(key.split(';')[k])
                k += 1
            i += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(col,
                  index=index
                  )
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
                       0
0             dt_notific
1     dt_inicio_sintomas
2  bairro_resid__estadia
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Gustav, unfortunately Im still in trouble.

I'm getting an out of range error, probably because my scrapped data is in a list object (j2 below) and I can't transform that to a multiline string using ''''

what I've tried to do was to prettify with indents, but still got the same error

col.append(key.split(';')[k])
IndexError: list index out of range

what i have tried:
    j2 = j['features']
    j2Str = json.dumps(j2)
    val = j2Str.replace(r"u\ufffd", "?").replace(r"\ufffd", "?")
    val = json.dumps(json.loads(val), indent=4)
    j = json.loads(val)